# Application pool memory gets out of control after updating dlls

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, performance, svn, memory-usage

We are experiencing Memory issues every time we update the dll's using SVN. The IIS process(w3wp.exe) takes up more than 1GB of memory which is usually 300 - 400 Mb under normal conditions. So every time we update dll's we had to recycle the application pool. Is it because the old dlls are still cached even after updating them? Do we need to follow any specific procedure for updating the dll's?

Can someone please advise me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried waiting for a while, and seeing what happens?

I would **guess** its posible its caching the old dlls for a while, perhaps while its serving old clients? In short i would leave it running, and only if this boks actualy runs out of memory would i consider this a problem.